# Need op-amp "window clipper", clipping below and above some range of DC

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, voltage-clipping

I need to design a kind of window clipper. It should work like this:

[image: Input voltage vs. output voltage graph]

Conditions:

- Vin: 0-6 V, Vout: 0 V
- Vin: 6-8 V, Vout: 0-3 V
- Vin: 8-10 V, Vout: 3 V

There are some example values, I need to be able to adjust range of clipping.
I don't need shift and scale circuit and I don't need positive & negative clipper. I'm working with positive DC only (I can provide **symmetrical** supply for op-amp if needed). It's about translating some section of input **range** to an output within some other range.

I hope I made myself clear but in case of some other questions, please write.

Comment: not the best-researched question, honestly, took me 10 seconds to type "positive negative window clipping opamp" into google until I found a resource so that I didn't have to draw the schematic myself, but oh well, it wasn't here yet. So there's your answer.

Comment: You say you don't want a shift and scale circuit and you don't need a positive or negative clipper...but that's exactly what you are describing. A circuit that shifts the input by 6V and then scales by 1.5, and then two diode rail clamps to clamp the output to between 0 and 3V (with the rails being chosen to account for the diode voltage drop so it is precisely 0 and 3V).

Comment: yep, you very much need a scale and shift, what do you think mapping 6-8 V to 0-3V is but scaling and shifting?

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen, your words make my mind hit the right track. I would like to +1 your comment, but i apparently i can't.

Answer (score 4):

that was an easy search: Analog devices has an  [application note](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/op-amp-precision-positive-negative-clipper-using-lt6015-lt6016-lt6017.html) on "Op Amp Precision Positive & Negative Clipper" using one of their opamp models, but you can basically use any rail-to-rail opamp (or an opamp who's got enough headroom given your power supply).

The schematic is dead simple. It's just a comparator with a diode.

[image: low/high clipper with optional output buffer]

(OUTBUFFERED is optional, if you wanted to drive some larger load to it).

Note that it's important that there's high impedance of your voltage source (done by R1 here). Otherwise, the opamps won't be able to "pull" voltages outside their maximum ranges straight.

For adjustable clipping voltages, all you need to do is adjust V3 and V5. That can simply be done by using potentiometers between V+ and V- to set these voltages – these voltage dividers aren't loaded (there's practically no current that flows into an opamp input).

You would then take the output OUT and amplify it (simple non-inverting opamp amplifier, the second-most-basic of all opamp configurations) and then you'd use another opamp voltage adder to add your least input voltage to it. Make sure you use significantly larger resistor values than R1 for your amplifier – that makes sure you're not loading the clipped voltage.

Think in building blocks! This takes 4 opamps, which can readily bought in a single package, and a few resistors, and two diodes. It's a very simple circuit to understand, and there's no complicated feedback between opamps that needs to be understood.

Comment: Can't you just make an offset and scaling circuit that re-biases 6V to 0V and then amplifies with a gain of 1.5? And then use diode clamps to a 0V and 3V rail on the output?

Comment: I understood it as one of the requirements that OP wanted to *externally* give the clipping voltages. But I wasn't very sure, to be honest. Also, diode clamping is somewhat inaccurate by itself.